# wGate driver working-Parallel NFET

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, charge-pump

[Reference](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps4811-q1.pdf?ts=1682436754209&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

With context to the following image.

[image]

From the input pin, which can be interfaced with CMOS logic. The highlighted enhancement type PMOS & NMOS pair acts as an inverter pair, right? (basically switching action, when PMOS is ON, the NMOS would be OFF & vice versa) this would be to prevent short of V<sub>S</sub> to the ground, I presume.

I didn't understand the connection between the PU and PD pins as well (the drain of the internal PMOS connected with the drain of the internal NMOS) is this correct to say?
Following this it is connected to the Gate of external FET Q1.

Are Q1 & Q2 acting as the load of the CMOS inverter?

I don't understand the connection of the BST to the SRC pin.
Although I'm new to this kinda circuit from the tutorials I referred the need of the Gate driver is based on the fact the FET (high side) needs V<sub>G</sub> > V<sub>S</sub> and hence the bootstrap power supply/capacitor is used to provide V<sub>Supply</sub> + V<sub>C<sub>BST</sub></sub> to the gate of the external FETs.

The above is not the case here.

Just need help with the working; I'm clearly having problems understanding the same.
Basically the BST, PU, PD & SRC pins.

Comment: It's both *drains* which are connected together by joining PU to PD

Comment: My bad, I meant to say the same. How does this connection help when it's connected to the Gate of the external FET, Isn't our motive to Drive the Gate voltage? Instead, the BST is connected to the source of both the external FETs. How is this Gate driving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly summarised the states of the two internal MOSFETS. One is off while the other is on, under control of the potential at INP. By joining PU to PD, this produces one of two conditions:

1. INP is high, the lower MOSFET is "on", and it pulls the potential at PU/PD *down* to 0V.
2. INP is low, the upper MOSFET is "on", which pulls PU/PD *up* in potential, to whatever potential is at its own source.

In this way gate potentials for Q1 and Q2 are raised and lowered under control of INP.

As for \$C_{BST}\$, its purpose is to raise potential at the gates of Q1 and Q2 *beyond* 48V (necessary to switch them *fully* on, in this [source-follower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain) configuration) during the period when the external MOSFETs Q1 and Q2 are supposed to be on.

Capacitor \$C_{BST}\$ needs to be charged ("topped up") only during the period when the MOSFETs are *off*. That's when Q1/Q2's source, node SRC, is at 0V potential. By connecting the bottom end of \$C_{BST}\$ to SRC, this allows \$C_{BST}\$ to charge up to whatever potential is at \$V_{AUX}\$ or the internal 12V source, during this off period.

Then, during the subsequent *on* period, SRC rises in potential, and the top of \$C_{BST}\$ (already at +12V) rises with it. Because the upper internal MOSFET is on at this point, it's the top of \$C_{BST}\$ which is effectively connected to Q1/Q2's gates, ultimately taking those gates to nearly \$48 + 12\$ volts.

In other words, the \$C_{BST}\$ is able to charge during the off period, and then "follow" the rise of SRC during the on period, due to being connected directly to SRC.

Comment: I have just edited my answer as you have posted yours.  :D  And you have made a mistake with 2xVs. Check the supply voltage!

Comment: @EdinFifić Thanks for the heads up, and the correction! Sorry if I stepped on your answer.

Comment: No, I don't feel like you stepped on my answer and we are supposed to offer our own explanations so that the questioner can see it from different angles and better understand. Still you should note that Cbst charges to only 12V from the internal or external source, so you still have an error.

Comment: @EdinFifić I submitted too quickly, I've fixed that too.

Comment: I understand, we all make mistakes in a rush, and the devil always hides in the details.

Comment: @EdinFifić I wasn't even in a rush, I was just lazy! I took half an hour to write the answer, and couldn't take 30s to make a correct edition.

Answer (score 1):

R<sub>LOAD</sub> is the load here. 
Q1 and Q2 are the output transistors or load drivers. 
The internal pair will have a brief moment of time (nanoseconds usually) during transition between high and low output when they are shorting the positive supply voltage to ground and that's why those two leads are left as an option or to give different configuration options.
The BST works in conjunction with SRC as it goes to ground during OFF time, and goes up to the positive voltage during Q1 and Q2 ON time.

> I don't understand the connection of the BST to the SRC pin. Although
> I'm new to this kinda circuit from the tutorials I referred the need
> of the Gate driver is based on the fact the FET (high side) needs VG >
> VS and hence the bootstrap power supply/capacitor is used to provide
> VSupply + VCBST to the gate of the external FETs.
>
> The above is not the case here.

You understand the need of Vg needing to be above Vs in order to drive the external MOSFETs, you don't understand the BST to the SRC connection and then you confidently state "the above is not the case here" while it is evident from your later comments that you actually don't understand as much as you think you do.

When the external MOSFETs are off, the Rload pulls the SRC pin to ground. 
At the same time, C<sub>BST</sub> is charged either through the internal "charge pump" 12V source or through an optional external 12V source. 
When the output transistors are on, the upper end of the Rload, as well as the SRC pin, are rising up towards the +48V supply voltage Vs. 
As the C<sub>BST</sub> capacitor's lower end is at the same point and its upper end (on BST pin) is 12V higher (it is charged now), its upper end will always be 12V above the voltage at the Rload and SRC pin, meaning once the Q1 and Q2 are fully ON, the BST pin will be at 48V+12V or +60V potential, which is needed to keep the output transistors fully ON and the output at Rload shorted to the full supply voltage through them.

Comment: Could you also explain how is the Gate driving happening in context to the bootstrap capacitor? The connection of BST to the SRC pin doesn't make sense as to how it'd help keep the NMOS above V(th)

Comment: I got very little of what you said, do you want me to rephrase my question?

Comment: @Harkirat I have added one sentence to answer your question here. Feel free to ask more if it's unclear. I'm just busy right now, so I keep my answers short.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I was referring to a series configuration of back to back nfets which I was trying to correlate with. I’m trying to learn and link my inferences from other circuits so I can get better. I’ll get back to you after I go through all the answers.

Comment: “As the CBST capacitor's lower end is at the same point and its upper end (on BST pin) is 12V higher (it is charged now), its upper end will always be 12V above the voltage at the Rload and SRC pin” when you say this the upper portion is essentially the source of the internal pmos right? Which in turn with the fact when inp is low drives V(G) above source. Is this right?

Comment: @Harkirat Correct. Cbst supplies the upper MOSFET in the IC, which turns on when INP is low. That MOSFET turns the Q1 and Q2 on, which connect the VS (+48V) directly to the Rload, and as the Rload keeps going up towards +48V, the Cbst capacitor is "riding on top of it", always providing a 12V higher voltage to the BST pin, which ends up going to the PU pin, keeping the Q1 and Q2 MOSFET gates always 12V above their source electrodes (when the upper internal MOSFET is on). When INP goes high, the lower internal MOSFET turns on and shorts Q1 and Q2 gates to their source pins to turn them off.

Answer (score 1):

SRC is the source of the output MOSFET.  PU and PD are Pull-up and Pull-down of the gate drive.  BST is the bootstrap voltage.

Since the two external FETs are in parallel, they can be treated as a single FET for our purposes.  So to turn the external FET off, the external FET gate must be pulled down to the external FET source.  To accomplish this, the N-channel internal FET is turned on while the P-channel internal FET is off, which pulls the gate down to the source voltage.  Hence the term "pull down" (PD).

But to turn the external FET "on" the external FET gate voltage should be *higher* than the external FET source voltage by 8 volts or so.  If we want the output of the external FET switched on and able to rise all the way up to VS, we must generate a voltage that can go higher than VS.  So we make a floating power supply that whose negative output is tied to the external FET source.  We use this to power the gate drive, allowing the FET to turn on all the way up to VS.  This floating supply is called the bootstrap voltage (BS).  Since the p-channel internal FET pulls the gate up to the bootstrap voltage, it is called a pull-up (PU).

PD and PU are brought out separately, because some IGBTs and FETs turn off more slowly than they turn on.  By using different gate resistors in the two outputs, the rise time of the gate signal can be slowed down, turning the FET on more slowly and balancing the on- and off-times.  This can be important when using the part with a low-side driver to prevent shoot through.